# No entries shown in Dojo Data Grid

Tags: xpages, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have got an Xpage with an Restservice (viewJsonService). If I test the RestService with the pathInfo I can see all Documents of the pointing view.

I bind the RestService to a DataGrid with 3 DataGridColumns. The DataGridColumns are pointing to the programmatical name of 3 default columns.

If I preview the Xpage in the Browser I can't see any data. Does anyone has got an idea where the problem can be?

```
    <xe:restService id="restService1" pathInfo="data">

        <xe:this.service>
            <xe:viewJsonService
                databaseName="Bewerbermanagement.nsf"
                defaultColumns="true" viewName="($AllDocuments)">
            </xe:viewJsonService>
        </xe:this.service>
    </xe:restService>
    <xe:djxDataGrid id="djxDataGrid1" storeComponentId="restService1"
        rowsPerPage="30">
        <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="autoWidth" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
            <xp:dojoAttribute name="columnReordering" value="true"></xp:dojoAttribute>
        </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn1" label="Datum"
            width="100px" field="$4">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn2" label="Absender"
            field="$2" width="100px">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
        <xe:djxDataGridColumn id="djxDataGridColumn3" label="Subject"
            field="SUBJECT" width="100px">
        </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
    </xe:djxDataGrid>
```

Example Json-Entry:

```
{
      "@entryid":"1-0590EED09824B814C1257D80003A68C8",
      "@unid":"0590EED09824B814C1257D80003A68C8",
      "@noteid":"8F6",
      "@position":"1",
      "@siblings":7,
      "@form":"Appointment",
      "$4":"2014-10-27T17:27:39Z",
      "$2":"Joe Doe",
      "SUBJECT":"V\u00D6"
  },
```

Comment: Your example does work for me. Built project properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I changed the Application theme from OneUI V3.02 to OneUI. But I don't know why this has got an effect on building the DataGrid

Comment: It may be something to do with the OneUI theme. I would not trust any Extension Library controls with a theme prior to OneUIv2.1. OneUI theme pre-dates Extension Library.